# Pass a dynamic variable to HTML attribute's value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

So here I have a situation which I couldn't find an answer to online.
I have the following HTML:

```
<th ng-repeat = "type in ::extraIdentifierTypes track by $index">
<strong>
    <a href="#" ng-click="$parent.orderByField= 'extraIdentifiers[{{type.name}}]'; $parent.reverseSort = !$parent.reverseSort">{{type.name}}
        <span  class="sort-pos" ng-show="$parent.orderByField == 'extraIdentifiers[{{type.name}}]'">
            <span ng-show="!$parent.reverseSort">
                <i class="sort-by-asc"></i>
            </span>
            <span ng-show="$parent.reverseSort">
                <i class="sort-by-desc"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</strong>
```

On ng-click I am changing the value of a $scope variable called  `orderByField` to a string value `extraIdentifiers[{{type.name}}]`

Its actually an array whose index would be dynamically generated. But when I pass the index as `{{type.name}}` It is not evaluating the expression `{{type.name}}`.
How do I pass the `type.name` as a index to `extraIdentifers` ?

Comment: Can you please add some demo?

Comment: Actually I just solved it! Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to just concatenate the string and the dynamic variable like this:

```
'extraIdentifiers['+type.name+']'
```